# Highcharts.js question: is it possible to keep some part of chart in visible area always, even if "overscoll" option is set

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I need to show some empty space to far right of the chart. To do so I use "overscroll" option (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.overscroll). But if user zoom in chart and pans chart to far right there can be empty space without any part of candlestick chart displayed (https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqnfFq3CII). Please advise is it possible to implement following chart behaviour and how to do so: to keep some part of chart in visible area always, even if "overscoll" option is set and user pans chart to the far right? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
var ohlc = JSON.parse(ohlcStringified),
    volume = JSON.parse(volumeStringified);
var interval = ohlc[ohlc.length - 1].x - ohlc[ohlc.length - 2].x;

var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        panning: true,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1,
        enabled: false
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.2,
        overscroll: 50 * interval,
    },
    yAxis: [{
        height: '40%'
    }, {
        top: '40%',
        height: '30%',
        offset: 0
    }, {
        top: '70%',
        height: '30%',
        offset: 0
    }],

    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        id: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: ohlc,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        id: 'volume',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    }]
});
```

Here is live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ogorobets/bfcs9gx7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, however, it requires some custom logic. It can be achieved using `xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes` callback where you can check if the current axis minimum is greater than your limit (a value lower than maximum xData value). When it is true, set new axis extremes with your limit as a minimum value. Check the code and demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
  xAxis: {
    minPadding: 0.2,
    overscroll: 50 * interval,
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function() {
        var chart = this.chart,
            xData = chart.series[0].xData,
            maxValue = xData[xData.length - 5],
            min = chart.xAxis[0].min,
            max = chart.xAxis[0].max

        if (min > maxValue) {
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(maxValue, max, true, false);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p6d73nk8/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes